# Resolving Julia 0.4 deprecation of Uint64

Tags: julia, deprecation-warning

I want to create a 2D array of Uint64s in Julia 0.4. This worked in 0.3:

```
s = 128
a = zeros(Uint64, s, s)::Array{Uint64,2}
```

It continues to compile but gives me the notice

```
WARNING: Base.Uint64 is deprecated, use UInt64 instead.
```

I don't know what this message means. I've tried googling the error message but haven't found anything helpful. What is an equivalent line of code that will not produce any warnings?

Comment: You do not need the type annotation (`::Array...`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = 128
a = zeros(UInt64, s, s)::Array{UInt64,2}
```

Watch out for capitals!

Answer (score 4):

Doug's answer is correct, except that you can simplify it to

```
s = 128
a = zeros(UInt64, s, s)
```

You don't need the type annotation `::Array{UInt64,2}`. Defining `a = zeros(UInt64, s, s)` will create a variable which knows its type.

Note that the Julia error message was telling you what you had to do -- replace `Uint64` by `UInt64`. If you can think of a better way of rephrasing the message to be clearer, that would be useful to hear.

In general, type annotations are at best redundant when defining variables in Julia -- the type is automatically inferred from the type of the right-hand side, and this will be the type assigned to the variable being created.

Type annotations are used in Julia in two circumstances:
1. to define the type of variables *inside a composite type*
2. for multiple dispatch in function definitions, to specify which types a given method applies to.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the signature. Regarding the error message, it was correct except that the capitalization is really hard to spot! Maybe if the two types, without namespaces and in lower case, were equal strings, say "watch your capitalization"?